# How to serialize an object with xml string as field to xml and set property name for this field (Jackson Object Mapper)?

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I'm trying to serialize an object to xml with Object Mapper. An object's field is a xml string itself. I use @JsonRawValue so Jackson won't escape xml charactets, like `<` or `/>`. But, with @JsonRawValue Jackson ignores @JacksonXmlProperty annotation, and writes the string directly, omitting property name.

So this code:

```
public class Example {
   @JsonRawValue
   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "SOME_NAME")
   private String xml = "<xmlExample>123</xmlExample>";
}
```

produces:

```
<Example> <xmlExample>123</xmlExample> </Example>
```

When i want:

```
<Example>
    <SOME_NAME> <xmlExample>123</xmlExample> </SOME_NAME>
</Example>
```

So the proplem is that @JacksonXmlProperty doesn't work with @JsonRawValue. And i don't know how to get rid of @JsonRawValue, because without this annotation, Jackson escapes some xml characters.

UPDATE: Output generation code:

```
Example example = new Example();
String s = new XmlMapper().vriteValueAsString(example);
```

Comment: Can you add the way you generate the output, are you using com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper?

Comment: @justMe added generation code.Yes, i use com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.

Comment: Apart from you have a typo in writeValueAsString it says vriteValueAsString, it should just work, I have added an answer with desired output

Comment: @coolsv, which version fo `Jackson` do you use?

Comment: @MichałZiober i had 2.5.3 and yes, it was a cause of problem. Updated to 2.9.0, now everything works good, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

 public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Example example = new Example();
            XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
            xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
            String xmlString = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(example);
            System.out.println(xmlString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
<Example><SOME_NAME><xmlExample>123</xmlExample></SOME_NAME></Example>
```

Comment: The problem was with Jackson version. I had pretty old  - 2.5.3. After updating to 2.9.0 (last available in my work repo) everything works good. Anyway, thanks for help.

Comment: No worries, glad it is sorted.